# JS/React: How to enable/disable checkboxes based on value of other checkboxes when data is coming from multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

How can I enable/disable checkboxes based on value of other checkboxes when data is coming from multidimensional array?

[image: example]

If any of the  first tracks (pink) are checked, the first bus’s (pink) checkboxes should be enabled.
OR
If all of the first tracks (pink) are not checked, the first bus’s (pink) checkboxes should be disabled.

If any of the  second tracks (purple) are checked, the second bus’s (purple) checkboxes should be enabled.
OR
If all of the  second tracks (purple) are not checked, the second bus’s (purple) checkboxes should be disabled.

Here's a sandbox - https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-87m8g6?file=src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

you can use the random number generation along with date functionalities(avoiding duplicates)

> Math.random() * new Date().getMilliseconds()

. check below

```
<ul className="flex">
    {tracks.map((_, j) => {
      return (
        <li key={j} className="box">
          {pair.map((active, i) => (
            <div key={i} className="vertical flex">
              <label
                className="container"
                htmlFor={Math.trunc(
                  Math.random() * new Date().getMilliseconds()
                )}
              >{`${i + 1}`}</label>
              <input
                id={Math.trunc(
                  Math.random() * new Date().getMilliseconds()
                )}
                name={j}
                type="checkbox"
                onChange={saveChecked}
              />
              <span className="checkmark"></span>
            </div>
          ))}
        </li>
      );
    })}
  </ul>
```

i have fixed this. Please checkout below mentioned link.

https://codesandbox.io/s/unique-values-for-multi-dimentional-array-react-yzliem

Comment: I'm not quite sure how that answers my question. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this should do the work:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const tracks = new Array(4).fill(null);
  const pair = [false, false];
  const [activeBusses, setActiveBusses] = useState([[false, false],[false, false], [false, false], [false,false]]);

  function saveChecked(e) {
    const checked = e.currentTarget.checked;
    const busIndex = e.currentTarget.id;
    const trackIndex = e.currentTarget.name;
    const updateActiveBuses = [...activeBusses];
    updateActiveBuses[trackIndex][busIndex] = checked;
    setActiveBusses(updateActiveBuses);
    localStorage.setItem('activeBusses', JSON.stringify(updateActiveBuses));
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <h1>Track Send</h1>
      <ul className="flex">
        {tracks.map((_, j) => {
          return (
            <li key={j} className="box">
              {pair.map((active, i) => (
                <div key={i} className="vertical flex">
                  <label className="container" htmlFor={i}>{`${i + 1}`}</label>
                  <input
                    id={i}
                    name={j}
                    type="checkbox"
                    onChange={saveChecked}
                  />
                  <span className="checkmark"></span>
                </div>
              ))}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>

      <h1>Bus Recieve</h1>
      <ul className="flex">
        <li className="vertical box">
          {[null, null, null, null].map((_, j) => (
            <div key={j} className="flex">
              <label className="container" htmlFor={j}>{`${j + 1}`}</label>
              <input id={j} type="checkbox" disabled checked={activeBusses[j][0] === true && activeBusses[j][1] === true}/>
              <span className="checkmark"></span>
            </div>
          ))}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Are you sure you pasted the correct code?